# Adding fixed Gridlines Chart in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, charts, flexbuilder

Is anyone know how to adding fixed gridlines chart in flex, for example: I have a vertical axis which has a minimum value 0 and the maximum value 100 but I only want to display gridlines on values 30 and 70.
So please me....
thx

Answer (score 0):

This should work... might not be ideal for you but it's simple...

Set the minimum to -10 the maximum to 110 and the interval to 40 on the verticalAxis.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7c24.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf65a29-7fec